# ORA-04098: Simple trigger is invalid. Why?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, ora-04098

There is something wrong with this trigger. But what?

```
CREATE  TRIGGER MYCOOLTRIGGER
AFTER INSERT ON MYCOOLTABLE
REFERENCING NEW AS newRow
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
END  MYCOOLTRIGGER;
```

SQL Developer output:

```
Warning: execution completed with warning
TRIGGER MYCOOLTRIGGER Compiled.
```

Is there any way to get more info on this Warning?

P.S.

This question could use a better title. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Oracle` requires that you have something between `BEGIN` and `END`.

You can use `NULL` (a no-op):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYCOOLTRIGGER
AFTER INSERT ON MYCOOLTABLE
REFERENCING NEW AS newRow
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    NULL;
END  MYCOOLTRIGGER;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what the errors are:

```
show errors trigger mycooltrigger;
```